# Why is the session, server or browser keeps login me out?

Tags: php

I have been using my "login script" for a while with no problem at all.
But until recently i keep getting loged out. Sometimes i can be loged in for maby on hour.. and sometimes..just a few minutes. Should i change something in my code.. or is this a setting in apache2/php ?

**This is my config:**

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, $options); } 
catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

//SET HEADER
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

//START SESSION
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
    session_start([
        'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    ]);
}
```

I runt this config on every page.

**THIS IS HOW I CHECK IF LOGED IN**

```
//CHECK IF USR IS LOGGED IN
if(empty($_SESSION['usr'])){
    echo "<script>window.location = '/index.php'</script>";
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}
```

**EDIT**
Should `session_start();` run on all pages?
I had that before, but i changed it to `if(!isset($_SESSION....` for some reason...

Comment: Your script does not show where do you check for expired sessions.

Comment: @EriksKlotins i have edited my question with the check!

Comment: What is the value of your config/session.php?

In this file you can set the expiration time of your session, this would help in understanding what is causing the logout. 

It should look something like this:
`'lifetime' => 120`

Comment: @McBurgerKong Do you mean a file in my server? Or do you mean When i start the session? If you read my config code.. it says: cookie_lifetime => 8640... you can read it in my question?! Or is this a setting in my php config?

Comment: @BjörnC You need to call `session_start` *somewhere* in every request.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I can't recall why i use the `if(!isset($_SESSION...` so i will comment that line.. and see if an error will accoure.. or if it will solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request or passed via a cookie.

To resume the sessions you need to call the `start_session()` on every request.

No need for

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)...
```

Comment: I see.. i will try to comment that line..(remove the if) .. To bad i can't remember why i placed it there in the first time.. from the beginning i did not use it.. but then.. i must had some error.. or problem.. that got solved.. with that if statement..